# R: barplot in ggplot2 where the height of each bar is given

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

```
library(ggplot2)
mydat <- data.frame(type = c("A", "B", "C"),
                    height = c(0.9, 0.3, 0.4))
ggplot(mydat, aes(x = type, y = height, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Running the above code gives me the following error:

```
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

I would like to create a barplot with 3 bars: one for A, one for B, and one for C. The barplot's y-axis ranges from 0 to 1, and the height of the boxplots are 0.9, 0.3, and 0.4, respectively. Is it possible to construct this barplot using `geom_bar` where the height of each bar is already given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `geom_col` :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydat, aes(x = type, y = height)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

To use `geom_bar` you need to specify `stat = 'identity'`.

```
ggplot(mydat, aes(x = type, y = height)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```